# ¿Error al rellenar un input en powershell con ie?

Tags: windows, cmd, script, powershell

Parece ser que no me llegan los datos de la página, esta se me abre, pero me dice que el valor es nulo.

He probado con `id` y tampoco, estoy en versión 5.1 de power shell.

Éste es el código:

```
  clear-host

  $ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"


    $ie.navigate2("https://www.youtube.com/?hl=es&gl=ES")

    $ie.visible = $true

    $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input").value = "asdf"
```

Y éste es el error:

[image: error]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

no he ha quedado muy claro el requisito de tu solicitud, pero por lo que entendí estás mezclando 2 temas:

Uno es el poder abrir un navegador en cierta URL y el otro poder completar un input dentro de una URL.

Si lo que quieres es poder abrir un navegador con una búsqueda en Youtube, una manera de hacerlo es la siguiente:

```
$search = "powershell"
$search.Replace(" ","+")
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate2("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=$search")
$ie.visible = $true
```

En donde la variable **search** específica el valor a buscar. Si te fijas en la segunda línea, utilicé el método *Replace* ya que al hacer la búsqueda con términos que contengan espacios, éstos son reemplazados con signos de más (+).

El resultado de lo anterior debe abrir una nueva ventana de IE con la búsqueda en Youtube del término "powershell".

**Editado:**

Con tu comentario, revisé un poco y pude llegar a esto:

```
$searchBar = "masthead-search-term"
$buttonId = "search-btn"
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate2("https://www.youtube.com/?hl=es&gl=ES")
$ie.visible = $true
while($ie.Busy) { Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100 }
$doc = $ie.Document
$doc.getElementById($searchBar).value = "PowerShell"
$doc.getElementById($buttonId).click()
```

Agregué una espera mientras carga la página, para luego si filtrar el campo de búsqueda y el botón de buscar. Con lo anterior deberías poder realizar lo que tienes en mente.

Comment: pero si quieres interactuar con la pagina entoces como por ejemplo darle al boton de buscar con id ="search-btn"

Comment: el probelma es que quiero escribir en el input directamente no a traves de la url

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta con tu solicitud.